# Duplicate entries in apache solr index upon reindexing in Drupal

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-6, solr, duplicates

I am using apache solr search integration on my Drupal 6 website: [govoluntourism.com](http://govoluntourism.com). I have my search results themed using views and a search-result.tpl.php file.

The search-result.tpl.php contains:

```
$nid = $result['fields']['nid']['value'];
echo views_embed_view($name = 'search', $display_id = 'default', $nid);
```

When I add content to my site and run cron, it seems that duplicate entries are being made in the apache index, because I am getting duplicates in the search results only of the content that was previously indexed.

Is this a server-side issue or a mistake in my configuration? Not sure where to go from here.
thanks.

the site is: [govoluntourism.com](http://govoluntourism.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your site and the duplicate search results all point to the same nodes, so that means you probably don't have actual duplicate content.

The first thing to do if you suspect your index is corrupt and you can't find the problem, is probably to reindex all of your content. You can do that by going here: http://govoluntourism.com/admin/settings/apachesolr/index.

Next, you can choose "Delete the Index", then "Re-index All Content". What this will do is rebuild your entire index from scratch. Note that if you choose "Re-Index All Content", it will happen immediately. If you have cron running, cron will slowly rebuild the index, which will use less resources but take much longer.

Once you have done that you'll have a better idea of what's going on.

If that doesn't work then you probably have an issue with the search results theme customization.

Comment: Thank you, this has taken care of the duplicates. I'll have to see if new duplicates are created as new content is added and indexed to the site via cron runs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to query Solr directly? If you have duplicate there, the problem is that you are importing the content duplicate.